# Flutter shared preferences same key multiple values

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I just created a username login screen and I store that data in shared preferences. But when I register the new user, the old data (username, password) overwritten. Is there just 1 data for 1 key ? I will use sql lite if necessary but I just wondered.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data stored in SharedPreferences can be edited and deleted. SharedPreferences stores the data in a key-value pair. Yes There Is just 1 data for 1 key for same key you can't store multiple value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list instead of one data
Save:

```
 prefs.setStringList('key', yourList);
```

Retrieve:

```
 var yourList = prefs.getStringList('key');
```

Comment: Tried, does not work

Comment: You can set a multi username in a list with setStringList here an exemple :              saveStringListValue () async
  {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList("usernamelist", ["username1", "username2", "username3"]);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the older value every time when you register a new user
for example you have a register button so every time user press that you should provide a remove value line

for instance:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: ()async{
                 var removeval = await prefs.remove("//your key here")     }
 child: Text("Register")
)
```

Comment: It's already removed the value, I mentioned it.  This is not the problem though